# Error in SQL Server in network programming

Tags: c#, sql-server, networking

I have 2 databases. The first one is created by SQL Server Express and the second one is created programatically.

I can work with them easily but the problem occurs when another user wants to login to them. I tried to add user to my databases with `Create user[Domain\User] for login ...` command.

This command worked for the first database but for second one I receive this error:

> "The server principal 'Domain\User' is
>   not able to access the database
>   'DBName' under the current security
>   context."

or this error:

> login failed for this user

Note that my program is used in network.

please help me

Comment: Please be more specific about your second database and how you try to access them. Do you use a webapplication?

Comment: Show us **how** you programmatically create your second database!

Comment: In order to use the `CREATE USER..... FOR LOGIN...` you would have to create a **login** first, using `CREATE LOGIN ...... `

Comment: No i use windows application.i use this code to create my 2nd DB : "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
        "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
        "FILENAME = 'MyPath\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " +
        "SIZE = 2MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
        "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
        "FILENAME = 'MyPath\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " +
        "SIZE = 1MB, " +
        "FILEGROWTH = 10%)".I used Create Login too but i recieve "The server principal ... " error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess: If the user and the server are in the domain the network want be any problem. You must add the login to the instance and assign it to a database along with the roles for the user.